# istio EKS intermittent timeout issues with reaching the application when changing from multi-AZ to single-AZ nodegroup

Tags: amazon-web-services, timeout, amazon-eks, istio

I've multi-AZ nodegroup with istio installed in aws EKS cluster. It's working fine. When I add a new node group in single AZ and migrate the workloads to the new single AZ node group then remove the previous multi-AZ node group, it shows intermittent timeouts with accessing the application that's currently in the new single AZ nodegroup.

When I keep both the node groups , there's no issues in accessing the application. Intermittent timeouts are showing after migration & when I completely remove all nodes from the initial multi-AZ node group, or when reducing number of nodes in multi-AZ nodegroup from 18 to a low number, say 2.

Here's the destinationrule:

```
    ---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: dest
  namespace: mng-api
spec:
  host: srvc.mng-api.svc.cluster.local
  trafficPolicy:
    loadBalancer:
      simple: RANDOM
```

virtualservice

```
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: vsrvc
  namespace: mng-api
spec:
  hosts:
    - "mng.api.a******.com"
  gateways:
    - "default/default-gateway"
  http:
    - route:
        - destination:
            host: srvc.mng-api.svc.cluster.local
```

What would be causing the issue

I want to migrate the workloads from existing multi-AZ nodegroup to single-AZ nodegroup. I added a new node group in single AZ and migrate the workloads from multi-AZ nodegroup, then removed all nodes in the multi-AZ nodegroup. Now it's showing intermittent timeouts with reaching the application hosted in single-AZ nodegroup

It's back to normal when I rollback the changes, ie. migrate the workloads to the multi-AZ node group. But my requirement is to use single-AZ nodegroup